# this_thread / chrono has not been declared

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, c++-chrono

I have checked many StackOverflow posts, but no answers solve my problem.

I get 2 errors:

`g++ .\main.cpp -fopenmp -o test`

```
.\main.cpp:12:14: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
  12 |         std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(20000) );

.\main.cpp:12:37: error: 'chrono' has not been declared
  12 |         std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(20000) );
```

My current G++ version is:

> g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0

The code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(20000) );
        std::cout << "Number of available threads: " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Current thread number: " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have already tried `-std=c++11` from 11 & 14 & 17.

Comment: `std::this_thread` is part of `<thread>`, so that should not be failing, unless the compiler's implementation of `<thread>` is incomplete. But `chrono::...` needs to be `std::chrono::...` since you don't have a `using namespace std;` statement.

Comment: IIRC, you need WinGW 64 for thread support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's right but about your second error can you replace it with

```cpp
std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(20000) );
```

to

```cpp
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20000));
```

I think the first error depends from second, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I fixed the chrono error with your answer but the first one still here

Comment: I think you are forgetting something, because the only problem it gives me are all the calls with opm (not having it). This_thread does not give me any problems.